# Link Title Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the standard Google Maps API v3 to make a map with multiple pins.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to link this popop:

[image: google maps api]

Example: The user would click on a map pin, it would load this tooltip, and they could click on the tooltip (as a link) for more information.

Here is how I am generating my map:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapFrame123'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
    console.log(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your picture shows "Boston Naval Shipyard", that doesn't exist in the posted code. What does the code look like that generated the picture?

Comment: @geocodezip The same code, but the photo was generated from a different data set. I have an array that has urls that I would like the tooltip to link to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put HTML content into infowindows.  You don't specify what you want to link to, however you could do something like:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, 'http://bondi.com'],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5, 'http://coogee.com'],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3, 'http://cronulla.com'],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2, 'http://manly.com'],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1, 'http://maroubra.com']
];

...

infowindow.setContent('<a href="' + locations[i][4] + '">' + locations[i][0] + '</a>');
```

Comment: Can you also set the style of the infoWindow? or just the content?

Comment: you can style the content

Comment: but can you style the background color, border, and remove the 'X' (close) image? Or are these preset?

Comment: Not really.  Although you're now getting onto a different subject; you might be better asking a separate question about how to style the content of the infowindows

Comment: I will ask another question. Thank you very much for your help.